# ReactJS: How to get height of visible part of element when scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I fetch the visible height of div when it scrolled (Visited your profile in October):

[image]

The full div height - `127px`. I've tried to dancing with `getBoundingClientRect()`, but nothing has changed.

```
<div id="root">
  ...
  <div id="statisticsContainer">
    <p>
      <Icon/>
      Visited you profile in October
    </p>
    <div id="mainValueContainer">
      <p>0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the [`IntersectoinObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect the element coming into view, play around with the [`threshold`](https://dev.to/_hariti/master-the-rootmargin-in-intersection-observer-b3d) to get it detected when it's barely in view.
2. `Element.offsetHeight` gives you the actual height